# More efficient way of structuring flat array of parent and children

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the most efficient way of extracting some common (group) value from array and create a new array based on group, where each group element is preceding elements that belong in that group?

Less convoluted example:

```
const animals = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Acura",
    family: "Cats"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Atem",
    family: "Cats"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Scoba",
    family: "Dogs"
  }
];
```

Becoming this:

```
// expected output:
// [
//   {
//     family: "Cats"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Acura"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Atem"
//   },
//   {
//     family: "Dogs"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Scoba"
//   }
// ]
```

I have based my approach on loop inside the loop, and on the second loop I check if the looped item matches the group loop item. I think this is not the most efficient way of achieving this. So I am open to suggestions how to improve it, please.

My working attempt:

```
let items = [];

const families = [...new Set(animals.map(animal => animal.family))];

families.forEach(family => {
  items.push({
    family
  });
  
  animals.forEach(animal => {
    if (animal.family === family) {
      items.push({
        name: animal.name
      })  
    }    
  })
})
```

Comment: Why not something like this `{"Cats":[{"name":"Acura"},{"name":"Atem"}],"Dogs":[{"name":"Scoba"}]}`?

Comment: @HassanImam That is the structure that is required. Weird, but I have no leeway.

Comment: is the array sorted by family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first group your array based on `family` in an object accumulator and then use `Object.entries` and `flatMap` to convert in your desired format.

```js
const animals = [ { id: 1, name: "Acura", family: "Cats" }, { id: 2, name: "Atem", family: "Cats" }, { id: 3, name: "Scoba", family: "Dogs" } ],
      grouped = animals.reduce((r, o) => {
          r[o.family] = r[o.family] || [];
          r[o.family].push({name: o.name});
          return r;
      },{}),
      output = Object.entries(grouped).flatMap(([family, arr]) => [{family}, ...arr]);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a colsure over a hash table.

This works for unsorted objects.

```js
const
    animals = [{ id: 1, name: "Acura", family: "Cats" }, { id: 2, name: "Atem", family: "Cats" }, { id: 3, name: "Scoba", family: "Dogs" }],
    result = animals
        .reduce((families => (r, { name, family }) => {
            if (!families[family]) r.push(families[family] = [{ family }]);
            families[family].push({ name });
            return r;
        })({}), [])
        .flat():

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If the data is sorted by family, you could just check the last family and add a new object with `family` only if a new group starts.

```js
const
    animals = [{ id: 1, name: "Acura", family: "Cats" }, { id: 2, name: "Atem", family: "Cats" }, { id: 3, name: "Scoba", family: "Dogs" }],
    result = animals
        .reduce((r, { name, family }, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
            if (!i || last.family !== family) r.push({ family });
            r.push({ name });
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```